# R: unclear behaviour of tuneRF function (randomForest package)

Tags: r, optimization, machine-learning, data-mining, random-forest

I feel uncomfortable with the meaning of the `stepFactor` parameter of the [`tuneRF`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/randomForest/docs/tuneRF) function which is used for tuning the `mtry` parameter used further in the [`randomForest`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/randomForest/docs/randomForest) function.

The documentation of `tuneRF` says that `stepFactor` is a magnitude by which 
the chosen `mtry` gets deflated or inflated.
Obviously, since `mtry` is a number of variables chosen randomly, it has to be an integer, however I saw many examples on the net using `stepFactor=1.5`.
At first I thought that R uses by default next `mtry` equal to `floor(mtry_current-stepFactor)`, but it turned out that I was wrong.
Moreover, I do not understand the R commands displaying `search left... search right...` while `tuneRF` is working.
I thought it was the information on either inflating or deflating the `mtry` parameter but my suppositions did not turn out to be correct.

To sum up this long and not too graceful description of my doubts, my questions are:
why is `stepFactor` NOT an integer number??

How are subsequent `mtry` values chosen?
What searching left/right actually mean??

Any help would be very much appreciated!! :)

Comment: I don't have experience with `tuneRF`, though I've used sometimes the `randomForest` package. It should be an integer in theory, but maybe 1.5 can say that at each bootstrap replicate, `mtry` is inflated or deflated by a random choice of 1 or 2 predictors. It's just my guess.

Answer (score 10):

Below is a summary of how `tuneRF` works:

1. a. Set *mtry* to the default value of sqrt(*p*) for classification, and *p*/3 for regression (where *p* = total number of variables)

   b. Compute the out-of-bag (OOB) error (say error_default) for a Random Forest with *mtry* set to the default value found above
2. a. Look to the left: set *mtry* = default value/stepFactor. For instance, if stepFactor=1.5 and your default starting value is 8, *mtry* would be set to be 8/1.5=5.33, rounded up to the be an integer, which gives 6

   b. Compute the OOB error, say error_left
3. a. Look to the right: set *mtry* = default value*stepFactor. To continue with my example, *mtry* would be set to be 8*1.5=12

   b. Compute the OOB error, say error_right
4. i. If (error_default < error_right) OR (error_default < error_left), the best *mtry* is the default value

   ii. If the previous condition is not met, but the delta between errors_default and error_right/error_left is less than the *improve* parameter, the best *mtry* is the default value

   iii. Without any loss of generality, if the condition is not met, and if error_right < error_left, and if (error_default-error_right) > *improve*, set *mtry* to be mtry_right (12). From now on, always go to the right
5. If 4.iii. is verified, iterate: set *mtry* to be mtry_right*stepFactor (in my example, 12*1.5=18), compute the OOB error and compare it with the error obtained at the previous step (in my example, for *mtry*=12). If the error new error is smaller, and if the gain in error reduction is enough (i.e, >*improve*), select the new *mtry* and continue to repeat these steps, otherwise stop and return the current *mtry* as the best *mtry*

The smaller stepFactor you set (e.g., 1.1, 1.2), the more values of *mtry* you try (fine search), the bigger stepFactor you set (e.g., 2, 2.5), the less values you try (rough search). Also, with low values of *improve*, the search will continue longer.